How can I debug crash where a Tensorflow model is trying to allocate too much memory
My tensorflow model is 230MB in params, and using a 300MB dataset, but crashing after one epoch. It' training a CNN on a binary classification problem.
System has a 16GB of RAM and a RTX 4070Ti
After a single epoch I get a message suggesting it's trying to allocate 12.5 GB:
102/102 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0180 - accuracy: 0.6293 - precision: 0.0000e+00 - recall: 0.0000e+002024-04-12 08:04:29.166412: W external/local_tsl/tsl/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:83] Allocation of 12582912000 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
Killed

Reducing the batch size to 1 does not help, and I need to be able to train on batch sizes up to 64. Given the small size of my dataset this shouldn't be a problem.
The model (Total params: 60130177 (229.38 MB)):
def create_dual_stream_cnn_model(input_shape):
    # Define the inputs for each stream
    input = Input(shape=input_shape)
    
    # Stream 1
    x = Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(input)
    x = Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = MaxPooling1D(3, strides=3)(x)

    x = Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = MaxPooling1D(3, strides=3)(x)

    x = Conv1D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv1D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = MaxPooling1D(2, strides=2)(x)

    x = Conv1D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv1D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = MaxPooling1D(2, strides=2)(x)

    x = Conv1D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv1D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = MaxPooling1D(2, strides=2)(x)
    
    # Stream 2
    y = Conv1D(64, 7, activation='relu', padding='same')(input)
    y = Conv1D(64, 7, activation='relu', padding='same')(y)
    y = MaxPooling1D(3, strides=3)(y)
    
    y = Conv1D(128, 7, activation='relu', padding='same')(y)
    y = Conv1D(128, 7, activation='relu', padding='same')(y)
    y = MaxPooling1D(3, strides=3)(y)

    y = Conv1D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(y)
    y = Conv1D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(y)
    y = MaxPooling1D(2, strides=2)(y)

    y = Conv1D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(y)
    y = Conv1D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(y)
    y = MaxPooling1D(2, strides=2)(y)
    
    y = Conv1D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(y)
    y = Conv1D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(y)
    y = MaxPooling1D(2, strides=2)(y)
    
    concatenated = concatenate([x, y])

    z = Flatten()(concatenated)
    z = Dense(1024, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=L2(0.0001))(z)
    z = Dense(1024, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=L2(0.0001))(z)
    z = Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=L2(0.0001))(z)
    z = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(z)
    
    model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=z)
    optimizer = SGD()
    metrics = ['accuracy', 'Precision', 'Recall']
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=metrics)
    print(model.summary())
    return model


Train loop:
BATCH_SIZE = 64
EPOCHS = 400
K_FOLDS = 10

X = np.array(cropped_records)
y = np.array(dup_labels)
y = y[:,0].astype(int)
X = np.expand_dims(X, -1)

kf = KFold(n_splits=K_FOLDS, shuffle=True)

test_scores = []
fold_id = 0
train_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):

    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]

    X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.1)
    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
    validation_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_valid, y_valid))
    test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test, y_test))

    train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=100).batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(buffer_size=BATCH_SIZE*3)
    validation_dataset = validation_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(buffer_size=BATCH_SIZE*3)
    test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(buffer_size=BATCH_SIZE*3)

    logs_dir = 'logs/' + train_time + f'/{fold_id}'
    if not os.path.exists(logs_dir):
        os.makedirs(logs_dir)

    model = create_dual_stream_cnn_model((X_train.shape[1], 1))
    print_gpu_availability()

    tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logs_dir, histogram_freq=1)
    lr_scheduler = tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(exponential_decay_fn)
    model.fit(train_dataset, 
            epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1,
            callbacks=[lr_scheduler, tensorboard_callback])

    test_loss, test_accuracy, test_precision, test_recall = model.evaluate(test_dataset)
    y_scores = model.predict(X_test, verbose=0)
    y_scores = y_scores.flatten()
    test_fpr, test_tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_test, y_scores)
    test_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_scores)

    test_scores.append({'loss':test_loss, 
                        'acc': test_accuracy, 
                        'prec':test_precision, 
                        'rec':test_recall, 
                        'auc':test_auc, 
                        'fpr':test_fpr, 
                        'tpr':test_tpr})

    fold_id += 1


There are many ways to reduce the memory consumption of your training and it's a common problem for ML engineers.
First of all, it looks like you might be training on the CPU if I'm not wrong.
You need to install Nvidia Cuda drivers to be able to train on the GPU and utilize the VRAM on the GPU. If you're on Windows this can be quite tricky but it's doable. You can look up a guide on how to install the Cuda drivers for TensorFlow. I think you need to download around 3 different files from Nvidia's website and it requires an Nvidia developer account.
Your model complexity is very big it might be beneficial to make it a bit smaller so remove some of the Conv1D. Of course, this depends on how complex a classification task you have. I know that your model and dataset are small but you need a lot of RAM to fit all the tensors for a complex model during training. Maybe you can also change the type let's say to float16 or something that doesn't take up a lot of space.
You can also try and use mixed precision training. TensorFlow provides a way to perform mixed precision training which can reduce memory usage and increase speed by utilizing the Tensor Cores on the RTX 4070 Ti. You can enable this by using tf.keras.mixed_precision API.
If you haven't heard of it already you can use Google Colab where you usually can get free access to a T4 GPU which will be better than your RTX 4070 Ti for training. It also has all the necessary drivers installed for TensorFlow already. The only downside is that it can be difficult to run the training job for a long time since Colab will time out.
I hope that helps you out. :)
